# Javascript: play multiple audio files from a single HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm new to Javascript (from a Python background)

I need an HTML page with several buttons, each of which will play 5 seconds of an audio file starting a specified point in time.

Here's my current approach:

```html
<audio id="audio_file_1">
  <source src="path/to/file/audio_file_1.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio><br>
<audio id="audio_file_2">
  <source src="path/to/file/audio_file_2.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio><br>
<button onclick="play_slice()" type="button">Play</button>        
<button onclick="play_slice()" type="button">Play</button>        

<script>
  function play_slice() { 
  var x = document.getElementById("audio_file_1");
  x.currentTime = 10;
  x.play();
    setTimeout(function (){
      x.pause();
      }, 5000);       
    } 
</script>
```

Currently, 'audio_file_1' and the start time, 10 seconds, are hardcoded in the script. How can I pass these as variables to the 'play_slice()' function, so that the first button plays the first audio file from an integer number of seconds?

Comment: How do you want to pass on the variables? You want these to be specific values for each audio or user can change them ?

Comment: They're specific values, I know them already. The user doesn't need to be able to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Put some inputs in your HTML and read their values when the button is pressed :

```html
<audio id="audio_file_1">
  <source src="path/to/file/audio_file_1.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio><br>
<audio id="audio_file_2">
  <source src="path/to/file/audio_file_2.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio><br>
<input type="number" name="time" id="time" value="10" />
<select id="track">
  <option value="audio_file_1">audio 1</option>
  <option value="audio_file_2">audio 2</option>
</select>
<button onclick="play_slice()" type="button">Play</button>        
<button onclick="play_slice()" type="button">Play</button>        

<script>
  function play_slice() { 
  var x = document.getElementById(document.getElementById("track").value);
  x.currentTime = +document.getElementById("time").value;
  x.play();
    setTimeout(function (){
      x.pause();
      }, 5000);       
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will simply need to add an additional argument to your function as below. And if it is not passed, a default value, 10 for instance, will be assigned

```
<audio id="audio_file_1">
  <source src="path/to/file/audio_file_1.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio><br>
<audio id="audio_file_2">
  <source src="path/to/file/audio_file_2.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio><br>
<button onclick="play_slice('audio_file_1',10)" type="button">Play</button>        
<button onclick="play_slice('audio_file_2')" type="button">Play</button>        

<script>
  function play_slice(currentTime) { 
  var x = document.getElementById(audioId);
  x.currentTime = currentTime || 10;
  x.play();
    setTimeout(function (){
      x.pause();
      }, 5000);       
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: This works for getting the time value into the function as an argument. Can I also pass the id of the audio element as an argument to the function, so that a specific time point in a specific file can be played?

Comment: Great, thanks very much! That works. 'audioId' is missing from the function signature, but adding that fixed it. Cheers.